# Connect to FTP server without using hostname

Tags: ftp, hostname, iis-10

I have a VPS with IP address: 54.432.212.12
There are multiple sites running on it.

My IIS FTP site bindings are:
Site 1
Bindings: 54.432.212.12:21:www.mydomain.com
Physical Path: E:\mydomain\wwwroot

Site 2
Bindings: 54.432.212.12:21:www.domain3.com
Physical Path: E:\domain3\wwwroot

So currently I have to connect to site 1 using my hostname, via Filezilla:
Host: www.mydomain.com
User: www.mydomain.com|md_ftp

Now, I don't want to register ftp.domain.com. Is there
A. a way to connect to IP 54.432.212.12 directly and then based on the user that is connecting show the correct FTP folder?
or
B. to connect using a random domainname (which I don't own) , e.g. 54.432.212.12:21:www.whatevername.com

I looked into virtual hostnames, though I don't see how that would solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with IIS FTP you can use user isolation feature, you can find more on microsoft IIS guide on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-user-isolation-in-iis-7